# Parallel construction

Tags: parallelism

I found this sentence on the internet as an example of parallel construction:

> Please bring the bill after we have had some coffee or when your shift is over.

Can anyone explain to me why this sentence is considered to have a parallel construction?

Thank you!

Comment: Well, it really isn't. The internet is filled with junk ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It could be expanded to:

> Please bring the bill after we have had some coffee, or please bring the bill when your shift is over.

It is not a great example of a parallel construction, as the expanded version seems so odd.

<sub>I suppose the reason for asking for the bill when the waiter's shift is over is for the purpose of tipping.  It would be a very odd thing to say in a restaurant in the UK.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!